# Cannot create instance of ICaptureGraphBuilder2

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, directshow

*Win32 SmartDevice DLL project - VS 2008*

I'm trying to use the `ICaptureGraphBuilder2` interface, but when I try to create the istance using the following code:

```
CComPtr<ICaptureGraphBuilder2> pCaptureGraphBuilder;
hr = pCaptureGraphBuilder.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder);
```

`hr` is `0x80040154`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, Capture Graph Builder (`CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder` and `CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2`) is not available in Windows Mobile. It is only available on desktop.

The error code is `0x80040154` = `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` "Class not registered".

You only have a subset of APIs in Windows Mobile/CE.

Comment: The CameraCapture example (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\wce500\Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK\Samples\CPP\Win32\Cameracapture) uses ICaptureGraphBuilder2.

Comment: You might be correct, it is on MSDN as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924828.aspx I am under impression I read before that others have similar issues though. Sorry, no Win CE around to check.